# Expressions of JSONPath for rest assured in a list with maven dependesies

Tags: json, maven, testng, rest-assured-jsonpath, gpath

I am trying to fetch data which is in JSON format. I am using maven dependency, testng and rest-assured. I want to test Rest API.BUT getting an error of 
java.lang.NullPointerException
Here is my code -

```
public class CountBook {
    @Test
    public void BookCount (){
        // Specify the base URL to the RESTful web service
        RestAssured.baseURI = **URL HERE**

        // Get the RequestSpecification of the request
        RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();
        Response response = httpRequest.get("");

        // First get the JsonPath object instance from the Response interface
        JsonPath jsonPathEvaluator = response.jsonPath();

        List<HashMap<String, Object>> allBook = jsonPathEvaluator.get("books.findAll {it.pages == 352}");
        int countingBook = allBook.size();
        System.out.println(countingBook);

    }
}
```

How can I get rid of this?*int countingBook = allBook.size();* this line shows error. Here the list return null value.JSON is look like this

```
{
  "books": [
    {
      "isbn": "9781593275846",
      "title": "Eloquent JavaScript, Second Edition",
      "subtitle": "A Modern Introduction to Programming",
      "author": "Marijn Haverbeke",
      "published": "2014-12-14T00:00:00.000Z",
      "publisher": "No Starch Press",
      "pages": 472,
      "description": "JavaScript lies at the heart of almost every modern web application, from social apps to the newest browser-based games. Though simple for beginners to pick up and play with, JavaScript is a flexible, complex language that you can use to build full-scale applications.",
      "website": "http://eloquentjavascript.net/"
    },
    {
      "isbn": "9781491950296",
      "title": "Programming JavaScript Applications",
      "subtitle": "Robust Web Architecture with Node, HTML5, and Modern JS Libraries",
      "author": "Eric Elliott",
      "published": "2014-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "publisher": "O'Reilly Media",
      "pages": 254,
      "description": "Take advantage of JavaScript's power to build robust web-scale or enterprise applications that are easy to extend and maintain. By applying the design patterns outlined in this practical book, experienced JavaScript developers will learn how to write flexible and resilient code that's easier-yes, easier-to work with as your code base grows.",
      "website": "http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000262/index.html"
    },
    {
      "isbn": "9781593277574",
      "title": "Understanding ECMAScript 6",
      "subtitle": "The Definitive Guide for JavaScript Developers",
      "author": "Nicholas C. Zakas",
      "published": "2016-09-03T00:00:00.000Z",
      "publisher": "No Starch Press",
      "pages": 352,
      "description": "ECMAScript 6 represents the biggest update to the core of JavaScript in the history of the language. In Understanding ECMAScript 6, expert developer Nicholas C. Zakas provides a complete guide to the object types, syntax, and other exciting changes that ECMAScript 6 brings to JavaScript.",
      "website": "https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read"
    },
    {
      "isbn": "9781491904244",
      "title": "You Don't Know JS",
      "subtitle": "ES6 & Beyond",
      "author": "Kyle Simpson",
      "published": "2015-12-27T00:00:00.000Z",
      "publisher": "O'Reilly Media",
      "pages": 278,
      "description": "No matter how much experience you have with JavaScript, odds are you don’t fully understand the language. As part of the 'You Don’t Know JS' series, this compact guide focuses on new features available in ECMAScript 6 (ES6), the latest version of the standard upon which JavaScript is built.",
      "website": "https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/es6%20&%20beyond"
    },
    {
      "isbn": "9781449337711",
      "title": "Designing Evolvable Web APIs with ASP.NET",
      "subtitle": "Harnessing the Power of the Web",
      "author": "Glenn Block, et al.",
      "published": "2014-04-07T00:00:00.000Z",
      "publisher": "O'Reilly Media",
      "pages": 538,
      "description": "Design and build Web APIs for a broad range of clients—including browsers and mobile devices—that can adapt to change over time. This practical, hands-on guide takes you through the theory and tools you need to build evolvable HTTP services with Microsoft’s ASP.NET Web API framework. In the process, you’ll learn how design and implement a real-world Web API.",
      "website": "http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/index.html"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?? Here is my stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at CountBook.BookCount(CountBook.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:110)
```

Comment: Rest Assured uses `GPath`, not `JsonPath` to be exact. That's why you have the error

Comment: Then how can I solve? What is the way of using GPath in my case? Please help

Comment: Can add JSON to your question?

Comment: Yes I add it now

Comment: Added the answer

Comment: Is this exact line in your code: `httpRequest.get("");`? Does it have any argument which might be hidden from us? Or it's exactly like in the question?

Comment: Thanks there was a problem of mine.It's okay now

Comment: @Fenio I cannot but asking a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61586175/how-to-find-json-path-of-array-in-rest-assured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find one book you can use:

```
jsonPathEvaluator.get("books.find {it.pages == 352}").toString();
```

You can also make expected number of pages parameterized like this:

```
jsonPathEvaluator.param("expected", 352).get("books.find {it.pages == expected}").toString();
```

In order to find `List<>` you just use `findAll` instead of `find`

EDIT:

You used `findAll` method which returns a list of elements. You saved them to `List<String>` which is NOT a correct class.

Each book is a JSON Object and using. Each JSON Object is a HashMap<> of  the String is a name of parameter, like `pages` or `isbn`. The other parameter is an Object because in your JSON there are `String`s like `author` but also `Integer`s like `pages`.

So, the correct code to collect the List would look like this:

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> allBooks = jsonPathEvaluator.get("books.findAll {it.pages == 352}");
allBooks.forEach(book -> book.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " " + value)));
```

and to count the number of books simply do what you did before:

```
int bookCount = allBooks.size();
```

Comment: Now error is _java.lang.NullPointerException_
What dependencies do you use?

Comment: @Ferdousi Then you did something wrong. Can you update the question?

Comment: @Ferdousi Rest Assured only

Comment: @Ferdousi Updated the answer

Comment: I import this --
`
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
`
and get the same error

Comment: @Ferdousi Which line throws the exception? Can you also provide stacktrace?

Comment: int bookCount = allBooks.size();
this line

Comment: @Ferdousi Update the code in your question to what you have right now.

Comment: @Ferdousi Add stack trace of the exception

Comment: I also add it now